# Index Fits into RAM, but Still Paging

Tags: mongodb

My working set (`db.collection.totalSize()`) is **21 GB**. My indexes take up **3.5 GB**.

On a **16 GB** RAM machine, via `mongostat` I'm observing that page faults occur. Note that they occur even with queries that use the index.

Using `vmstat`, I can see heavy reads under the IO/bi section.

Lastly, using `db.serverStatus()` on the "admin" database, I've seen that the **resident** mem is `10.6` GB.

Given the fact that Mongo is using 10.6 GB, which obviously is more than my index, why would paging occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index should not save you from having to go to the Disk.

The database is using 10.6 of your 16 GB. This is at best half of your total DB size. If your apps are requesting different pieces of info, then the DB's cache will be less use full.  (While the index will probably be cached in memory, the index is only a small subset of the complete record)

The index will help you find the right location, but you may have to go to the disk to get it. MongoDB and most other DB's will Cache the most recent/often used results in memory.

Mongo DB calls the most commenly requested data the "Working Set"

See this [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/) for more info.

**EDIT**: More info on *DB's cache will be less use full.*

The cache can only contain X amount of data. Data that is in the cache will be returned from the cache ( without disk IO ). If your program is regularly requesting data that is not in the cache then the DB will have to resort to disk IO to get the data. The cache (here the DB) tries to use some algorithm to decide what to store in cache. The 'different' is referring to data that is different then what the cache thinks it should be storing.

I suggest you read up on caching in general for more info.

Comment: So searching index fits in RAM, but fetching the entire document s takes io and ram (which isn't there so uses paging?

Comment: @Kevin: added a few more line to clarify

Comment: Thanks SH. Clear, informative answer and helpful link. Based on your update and the link, its likely that the index fits in RAM, but the OS may put documents in RAM. Given that my RAM doesn't cover the working set, paging can occur as document may replace indexes in RAM, which then requires a page fault if needing to put the index in memory.

Comment: @Kevin You can also try improving your readahead figure and see if that uses up your 16GB ram properly, the OS will try and house as much of the working set as it can so a 10.6GB of working set for your db might mean your readahead is too low.

Comment: Hi Sammaye - could you please elaborate as to how I could improve my readahead figure?

Comment: @Kevin: I would suggest you search for So questions and/or open a new question. Helps to keep things on one topic.

Comment: @Kevin http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/05/10/thursday-5-diagnosing-high-readahead/ try a bit of that

Comment: @SH-, what does this mean: `If your apps are requesting different pieces of info, then the DB's cache will be less use full.`?

Comment: MongoDB does not do its own caching, it leaves all memory management upto the OS, it does cache the actual query itself though and the indexes used etc